# Javascript sorting with selector and options inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: this is what i have]

So I attached picture here showing how it is. Of course there will be a lot more devices. Any idea how to sort them by alphabet when choosing selectors letter...like all devices who have been chosen like A goes above B and etc.?

The list of devices will be generated dinamicly from json.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.sort()` function

For example, your array (or data source) is:

```
var data = ['C', 'E', 'A', 'D', 'B'];
```

For ascending order use:

```
var ascSort = data.sort();
```

And, for descending sort use (after ascending sort):

```
var descSor = ascSort.reverse();
```

Comment: and it will automaticly arange all div lines according to that letter?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. This method sort your data, and you can create your divs by iteration on the sorted dataset

Comment: well as you see in picture above there is a <select> with a,b,c,d,e,f and when you choose one of them the div with , for example i chose A and others are B, that div goes above all others in the first spot